# Should We Put our Washer and Dryer Outside?

Tags: appliances

We have very limited space in our home for a washer & dryer. We are thinking about putting them outside. We have an outdoor patio where 3 sides are part of the structure (the house). There is also a roof which is part of the house. The fourth side is open. The cement is a step up, elevated from the rest of the patio. We live in Southern California, in the high desert near Mojave. The winters get as low as 20 degrees and the summers up to 115 degrees. We have a lot of wind and some rainfall but not a lot. When it rains, it rains hard. Also the yard is mostly dirt so the dirt blows around a lot. Would this work? Would we still need the air vent? Should we wrap the gas line, wires, etc. What about putting them on a platform, off the ground?

Comment: `Would we still need the air vent?` If you mean a dryer vent, then yes. Lint is very flammable, you may only need to run it a foot through a wall but you still need to vent it away.

Comment: I'm unsure what you are trying to achieve from a platform or wrapping. The location sounds protected enough that freezing shouldn't normally be a problem. Blowing dust will be a problem, how much, I'm unsure. I'm inclined to say try it.

Comment: I would be concerned about the water supply hoses on the washer freezing if you get temperatures as low as 20 degrees.

Comment: There is a climate element to this question that's specific to the OP.  It might have value if edited to reference the other question, then ask the climate specific question.

Answer (score 1):

When I was stationed in Panama our gov't quarters included the washer and dryer outside. The term eludes me now, but our quarters we're raised so that the driveway went under the domicile. The washer/dryer sat on a cement driveway under the quarters, exposed to the Panamanian elements.
Lint collection consisted of a plastic box that attached to your exhaust hose. The lint and exhaust went through the box and the lint was caught by wire mesh. 
We actually bought the washer/dryer combo from the gov't after three years of our use. Contractors told us at the time the combo was at least ten years old. I paid $10 for both.
Then I sold them again three years later.
So, to your question, I'd say yes.
Good luck!

Comment: Funny.  As soon as I read the OP's question I was reminded of Ft. Clayton in Panama as well.

Comment: This is very common in Africa too.